# Has anyone recorded a cello version of Bach's Prelude No. 1 in C major (BWV 846)

Tags: recording, classical-music, johann-sebastian-bach

Note: I really mean CELLO version!  I'm sure I've heard it, but starting to think I imagine it.

It's also called 'Prelude and Fugue No.1 in C Major, BWM 846'.

I believe it's the warm-up piece Bach wrote for his students to prepare for the Well Tempered Clavier, but could be wrong.

Comment: The Bach Cello Solo No. 1 starts out very like the WTC Prelude No.1. They are not identical. Listen to them back to back and see what you think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pieter Wispelwey recorded a version with Richard Egarr on an album called "Gamba Sonatas" for the label [Channel Classics](http://www.channelclassics.com/j-s-bach-gamba-sonatas-riddle-preludes-baroque-perpetua.html).

Answer (score 1):

Wikipedia for [The Well-Tempered Clavier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Well-Tempered_Clavier) lists an [Ave Maria by Gounod](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:JOHN_MICHEL_CELLO-BACH_AVE_MARIA.ogg), based on the Prelude, for piano & cello, but I can't find anything else

Answer (score 0):

I realise this topic is pretty dusty but I personally found the recording by Yo-Yo Ma to be very enjoyable.

- Artist: Yo-Yo Ma
- Album:  Bach: Cello Suites Nos. 1, 5, 6
- Title:  Unaccompanied Cello Suite No. 1 in G Major, BWV 1007: Prélude

Links:
- Spotify: https://goo.gl/AJVt8W
- iTunes:  I'm not allowed to post more links, but you'll find it here.

If you want to see something truly remarkable, check this experiment by Astronaut Don Pettit (twitter.com/astro_pettit) featuring this cello version in space. I have not found another high-quality version of this but on the "SmarterEveryDay" - YouTube channel. While I can recommend the entire video, here's a link to the specific part where the title is played: https://goo.gl/vOS8MU

Best regards,
Philipp.

Comment: While this is a "Prelude No. 1" so to speak, this is actually a different piece; OP was referring to the first prelude of the Well-Tempered Clavier, whereas this is the first prelude from the six cello suites. Note the BWV number in the OP (846) and the BWV for the cello suite (1007).

Comment: Still a terrific recording though!